# Error "Class not found" using Composer PSR-0 autoloader on Eclipse Neon PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I am currently trying to build a new PHP project from scratch (inside a `git` repository), using Composer (for the very first time), on Eclipse Neon PDT with [Composer Eclipse Plugin](https://github.com/pulse00/Composer-Eclipse-Plugin) and [EGit](https://eclipse.org/egit/).

In order to start with something quite simple, I first installed the well-known library [PHP Markdown Lib](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown). I think that I had not getting problem for configuring the `require` setting, as running Composer correctly updates dependencies using:

```js
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3",
    "michelf/php-markdown" : "~1.7"
},
```

As described in the [Usage](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown#usage) section of the documentation of PHP Markdown Lib, I setup a PSR-0-compatible autoloader in my `composer.json` and generated the `autoload` file:

```js
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "Michelf\\Markdown" : "vendor/michelf/php-markdown/Michelf"
    }
},
```

On my PHP file, I have simply included the following:

```php
$input = file_get_contents('input.md');
use Michelf\Markdown;
$output = Markdown::defaultTransform($input);
```

All seem to be correctly recognized by Eclipse Neon:

1. the `namespace` and `class` rightly appear as *autocomplete* propositions (first screenshot)
2. the library is displayed in the outline of the document as *import declarations* (second screenshot)

[image: namespace-class]

[image: outline]

But, despite all my testings with these settings, the page is still displaying:

> Fatal error: Class 'Michelf\Markdown' not found

I have tested other formulations, such as `use \Michelf\Markdown;`: it is equally recognized by Eclipse Neon (autocomplete feature and document outline, as displayed on previous screenshots), but I still get the *fatal error*.

To ensure the autoload file was updated correctly, I have also executed the CLI [`dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload) command. Unfortunately, without more success at this time.

Right now, I suppose this problem seems [to be not directly related with PHP Markdown Lib](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/issues/263), but that I certainly forgot a step or made a mistake within my settings, which seem to fail to correctly set up the PSR-0 autoloader, even if all seem to be correctly detected by the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Try removing the `Markdown` bit since it doesn't look like it's part of the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to include composer autoload at the beginning of the file?

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```